# HTTP Request Profiling

Tags: http, profiling, ssl

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55577020/820410).

As the title suggests, I'm searching for an HTTP request profiler to measure latencies of each step eg: time taken for each of the following steps:

- TCP connection/handshake
- SSL handshake
- SSL session resumption
- request/response
- CPU consumption for SSL

I've tried using Jmeter but wasn't able to achieve what I want.

Is there some tool available for the above requirement?